# Concurrency with Java's LinkedList class

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Good Day,

I am having concurrency problems with a LinkedList in Java. I have an Object type called "Connection" which has as a member variable LinkedList of "MessageHandlers" called "listeners". I then have two different threads, one modifying and one iterating over the same LinkedList.

I've seen many many other StackOverflow questions that suggest to use the sychronized block of code, but that doesn't appear to be helping it all. I've also try creating the LinkedList as a concurrent linked list, but I am still receiving the

```
 Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

exception. Does anyone have any other suggestions to try? Here are some snipbits of my code...

```
public synchronized Object ReadObject() throws java.io.IOException
{
    Object obj = null;

    try
    {
        obj = input.readObject();

        synchronized(listeners)
        {
            Iterator<MessageHandler> i = listeners.iterator();

            while(i.hasNext())
            {
                i.next().MessageReceived(obj, this);
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {   
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return obj;
}
```

The above code is inside my connection object. It gets called from a function that has a socket's ObjectInputStream reading data from the socket."input" is an instance of ObjectInputStream.

```
public void addNewLoggedInUser(User user) throws Exception
{
    for(User u:loggedInUsers)
    {
        if(u == user)
        {
            throw new Exception("That user is already logged in");
        }
    }

    //Add the new users
    loggedInUsers.add(user);

    synchronized(user.getConnection().getListeners())
    {
        user.getConnection().getListeners().add(this);
    }

    this.SendGameStatusUpdateToAllLoggedinPlayers();
}
```

I then call the method **user.getConnection().getListeners().add(this)** and thus am getting the exception.

```
public Connection()
{
    //Initialize the variables to NULL
    socket              = null;
    output              = null;
    input               = null;
    receiveThread       = null;
    runReceiveThread    = false;
    listeners           = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<MessageHandler>());

    //Handle the ID counter. Now we have a unique ID for every connection that comes in
    connectionID = counterID;
    counterID = counterID + 1;
}
```

This is the constructor for the connection class. Notice he **Collections.synchronizedList**

Any ideas? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Are user.getConnection().getListeners() and listeners same instance in the synchronized block parameter?

Comment: [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) is thrown when you've altered a list (added/removed elements) while iterating over it. You can cause this exception with a single thread. You shouldn't need any sort of concurrent collection unless there are multiple threads which access the list simultaneously.

Comment: http://ideone.com/pUPCn as an example.

Comment: @George Thanks! I didn't understand what you meant for the longest time thinking I didn't explain the code well enough, because I thought your response was way off. Turns out, you are exactly right! I didn't see what I was doing till I did it again on a smaller example and saw the same Exception being thrown. Thanks for your help George!

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` isn't really a threading issue. It is cause by modification of a list locked by it's iterator. I think you are calling `addNewLoggedInUser()` from `MessageReceived()`. This would cause the concurrent modification exception since the calling function already has iterator lock on the linkedlist.

Answer (score 0):

The `synchronized` blocks look like they should work.  I would expect that there is activity in  methods called from within the `ReadObject` `synchronized` block which modify the list.  Do any of your `MessageHandler`s call or chain to a call to `addNewLoggedInUser` (or any other method that might update the listener list)?

If so, the thread would already have the monitor grabbed by the `ReadObject` `synchronized` block, and would be able to enter the block in `addNewLoggedInUser`.

Comment: yes, one of my MessageHandler's calls addNewLoggedInUser. I am not familiar with what the "monitor" is, so I will have to do some research on that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Go through BlockingQueue javadoc. It mentions a simple scenario as well that fits your requirements i.e.

```
class Producer implements Runnable {
  private final BlockingQueue queue;
  Producer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (true) { queue.put(produce()); }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
  }
  Object produce() { ... }
 }

 class Consumer implements Runnable {
   private final BlockingQueue queue;
   Consumer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
   public void run() {
     try {
       while (true) { consume(queue.take()); }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
   }
   void consume(Object x) { ... }
 }

 class Setup {
   void main() {
     BlockingQueue q = new SomeQueueImplementation();
     Producer p = new Producer(q);
     Consumer c1 = new Consumer(q);
     Consumer c2 = new Consumer(q);
     new Thread(p).start();
     new Thread(c1).start();
     new Thread(c2).start();
   }
 }
```